# Palette that gets single keystroke as input

Tags: functions, function-construction, notebooks, built-in-symbols, palettes

I could find many examples of user-made `Palette` with many buttons in it.

And drawing-tools Palette is not user-made, but it accepts **a single keystroke** as input.
(In menubar, Graphics > Drawing Tools)

But I haven't seen an example of user-made `Palette` that accept **a single keystroke** as input.

Can you create a simple Palette such that

> If I press `a` in the physical keyboard, then it will set variable
> `myvar` to `77` silently
> Otherwise it has no function at all

Comment: The shortcut keys are a feature of `Graphics`, not the palette.  And those keys have explicit support in the Frontend. i.e., they are not user extensible.  The closest you can probably get is via `EventHandler`.

Comment: Thank you, I've considered such case, in fact. That is a small shame.